# Installing gMSA on client remotely

Tags: powershell, windows-service

I succesfully created a gMSA in our AD production, I now want to link it to a host server/computer for testing (ex: launching schedule task).

To link the gMSA to the server, we need to install some powershell module and then run the following powershell command from the server:

```
Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity "serviceaccount"
```

My question: Is it possible to link/install the group managed service account (gMSA) to the server remotely from a management machine (or any machine that need that have powershell module) without having to run it directly from the server? (I don't want to install powershell modules on my clients.)